# Migrating MS Access Append Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, append

The below is an append query in MS Access. I have to migrate it to SQL Server which I can do. But I have question regarding the "!" used in the query generated from the query designer. I was unable to understand the design view.

```
INSERT INTO [TABLEX] ( COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 )


SELECT [TableA].[COL1], [TableA].[COL2], [TableA].[COL5],

IIf(Left([COL3],4) In (YYYY,XXXX),"YYYY - XXXX --- XXXXXX",[Name]) AS Name

FROM [TableC], [TableA] INNER JOIN [TableB] ON [TableA].[COL1] = [TableB].[COL1]

WHERE (((Left([COL3],4))<>"XXXX" And (Left([COL3],4))<>"YYYY" And

(Left([COL3],4))=[TableC]![COL1]) AND (([TableC].COL2)="-") AND (([TableA].[COL4])<>"MMM")) OR 

(((Left([COL3],4))="XXXX" And (Left([COL3],4))=[TableC]![COL1]) AND (([TableC].COL2)="-") AND 

(([TableA].[COL4])="ZZZ")) OR (((Left([COL3],4))="YYYY" And (Left([COL3],4))=[TableC]![COL1]) AND (([TableC].COL2)="-"));
```

Can someone let me know what T-SQL statement can accomplish the same work. Below are the instances where they appear.

(Left([COL3],4))=[TableC]![COL1])

Any advice would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: Try replacing the '!' with a '.' such as in '(([TableC].COL2)="-")'.

Comment: I'm aware of that option , I was just wondering what does that operator mean in the query desgin from where it is generated

Comment: I think it means the same thing in Access SQL as the dot in TSQL. When I used to do Access I would type a table name followed by an exclamation mark and a select list of field names would appear.

Comment: To be more specific: it means the item on the right of the mark is a member of the item on the left.

Comment: Yes I got clarity on it. Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access sometimes takes '.' or '!' when addressing column names with table. It is strange why it does that. But when you write the jet based queries in T-SQL. The '!' can be replaced by a '.'. This resolved my issue. And it is got nothing to do with the operators in T-SQL which I initially thought of.